# How to understand the equality about $(\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathrm{grad})\mathbf{q} $?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

For the relation, 
$$(\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathrm{grad})\mathbf{q} = (\mathrm{curl}\mathbf{q})\times\mathbf{q}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{grad}|\mathbf{q}|^2,$$
is there any physics, geometry, or basic intuitive explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You obtain the above relation by putting $\vec A=\vec B =\vec v$ in the following relation:
$$\nabla(\vec A\cdot \vec B)=(\vec A\cdot \nabla)\vec B+(\vec B\cdot \nabla)\vec A+\vec B \times (\nabla \times \vec A)+\vec A \times (\nabla \times \vec B)$$

Now as you can see, the physical/geometrical/intuititve explanation for your relation is the same as that for this relation.

And this can be easily done as L.H.S. denotes the gradient of the scalar field "*the projection of $\vec A$ on $\vec B$*" and hence on.

Answer (score 0):

to begin with this is down to algebra. if we let the components of the vector field $q$ be $(f,g,h)$ and use subscripts for differentiation then, looking at the $x$-component
$$
((\nabla\times  q) \times q)_x = ((\nabla\times  q)_yh-(\nabla\times  q)_zg \\
=(f_z-h_x)h-(g_x-f_y)g \\
= (f_yg+f_zh) - (g_xg+h_xh)
$$
if we insert an extra term $f_xf$ in each parenthesis the value of the whole is not changed and we have:
$$
(f_xf+f_yg+f_zh) - (f_xf+g_xg+h_xh) \\
= q\cdot \nabla f -\frac12 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f^2+g^2+h^2) \\
= \left(q\cdot  \nabla q -\frac12\nabla |q|^2 \right)_x
$$

Answer (score 0):

In fluid mechanics, $\vec{q}$ is the velocity of the fluid. The term $\vec{q}\cdot\nabla\vec{q}$ is the advective part of the total time derivative of $\vec{q}$. It describes the change in the velocity of the fluid as one travels along a fluid parcel. Such a change can happen because of two reasons:
(1) The magnitude of $\vec{q}$ changes. It is described by the $\nabla(q^2)/2$ term or (2) The direction of $\vec{q}$ changes. This happens because of the fluid's vorticity. If the vorticity $\vec{\omega} = \nabla\times\vec{q}$ has a component normal to $\vec{q}$ then it induces a change in direction.